# Sharing internet through ethernet port?

Tags: raspbian, networking, wireless, ethernet-port

I have a situation where I need to share the Raspberry Pi's internet connection through the ethernet cable.  The Raspberry Pi is already connected to the internet with a Wi-Fi dongle, but I'm not sure how to pipe that connection through the ethernet port.

The main problem is that everytime I plug in the ethernet cable, it seems to default to that for internet, even if none is available and my WiFi dongle does have internet available.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Of course that's possible!  Check out this site:
http://imranasghar.blogspot.com/2009/09/how-to-make-ubuntudebian-as-router.html

What you're wanting to do is routing on your Raspberry Pi so that the Ethernet connection is downstream from the WiFi dongle.  You can go ahead and skip the first few steps about DHCP since you'll only have one device, and can assign it any static IP in the range you specify.  Looks like you'll want to start on **Step 7** with the Forwarding and IPTables entries.

And probably lots of testing!  Good luck!

Comment: This looks promising.  +1 for now while I test it (might be a while), if it works I'll accept it.

Comment: I'm afraid I still can not get it to work.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

I found a tutorial video for this. Its super easy for windows user. Just share your wifi internet then plug your Ethernet cable to both PC and Rapberry Pi

https://youtu.be/2dBTDVr_fL0

Comment: Hello and welcome! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help). Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it is preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. In fact we're [enforcing this policy](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/842/5538): please edit so that the answer stands on its own should the link break in the future. If it is not edited within 48 hours it will be converted to Community Wiki.